# ¿El modulo row como funciona?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Tengo una duda sobre el modulo `row` ,quiero saber exactamente cual es su funcionamiento interno que es lo que hace sobre una tabla de datos en sqlite3:

Detallo el código abajo con un ejemplo simple pero no lo logro entender si por favor alguien me podría explicar `row`

```
import sqlite3 

[print(row) for row in data]   # <----por ejemplo ¿acá que es lo qué hace?
```

Answer (score 1):

En realidad `row` no es ningún módulo, es el nombre de una variable sin más. Lo que muestras es la sintaxis propia de las listas por compresión de Python, muy mal usada en este caso por cierto.

Lo que ese código hace es iterar sobre la variable `data` con un ciclo `for`, `row` es el nombre que le damos a la variable asociada al ciclo y que en cada iteración del mismo se asociará al item correspondiente de `data`.

Para verlo más claro, un ejemplo en el que `data` es una lista:

```
data = [2, 3, 7]

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

> ```
> 2
> 3
> 7
> ```

le podemos dar el nombre que queramos, intentando siempre que sea descriptivo:

```
for número in data:
    print(número)
```

El código que muestras hace exactamente lo mismo, solo que hace uso de la sintaxis de las listas por compresión. La sintaxis básica es:

```
[expresion for item in iterable]
```

Por cada item del iterable se evalúa la expresión y el resultado se usa como item de la lista. Puede complicarse mucho más, por ejemplo con condiciones o mediante anidamiento:

```
[expresion for item in iterable if condición]
[expresión_a if condición else expresión_b for item in iterable]
[[expresión for item in subiterable] for subiterable in iterable]]
....
```

Esta sintaxis permite que en una única instrucción generar una lista a través de la transformación de los elementos de un iterable cualquiera. No solo son una forma concisa de generar listas, sino que son considerablemente más eficientes que el uso de un ciclo `for` + `list.append`, la razón principal es porque se elimina la llamada a `list.append` precisamente.

Pero hay casos en los que jamás deben usarse, y el que muestras es uno muy típico:

```
[print(row) for row in data]
```

itera sobre data, en cada iteración un item de data se asigna a la variable row y se evalúa la expresión `print(row)`. Esto lógicamente llama a `print` que imprime el valor de `row` y retorna `None`. Ese `None` que retorna `print` en cada iteración se agrega a la lista generada, resultado: una lista repleta de `None` que no sirve para nada:

```
>>> data = [2, 3, 5]
>>> lista = [print(row) for row in data]
2
3
5
>>> lista
[None, None, None]
```

el resultado es que es considerablemente menos eficiente que hacer simplemente

```
for row in data:
    print(data)
```

que imprime también los items de `data` pero no genera ninguna lista inútil.

Si sería útil por ejemplo si queremos aplicar un filtro a la lista, por ejemplo obtener los impares:

```
data = [1, 2, 6, 7, 3]
impares = [número for número in data if número % 2]
```

> ```
> >>> impares
> [1, 7, 3]
> ```

o aplicar una función a cada item y obtener el resultado en otra lista:

```
import math
data = [1, 2, 6, 7, 3]
raices = [math.sqrt(número) for número in data]
```

> ```
> >>> raices
> [1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 2.449489742783178, 2.6457513110645907, 1.7320508075688772]
> ```

En tu caso, según el contexto, seguramente se está iterando sobre algun objeto que representa una tabla (como una lista de lista) o el resultado de una consulta a la base de datos, por lo que `row` sería eso, cada fila de la tabla:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.execute("CREATE TABLE persona (nombre VARCHAR, dni VARCHAR)")
cursor = con.cursor()

datos = (("Juan", "1234564585Z"),
         ("Pedro", "45785952156X"),
         ("María", "54875952145E"))

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO persona(nombre, dni) VALUES (?, ?)", datos)

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM persona")
for row in cursor:
    print(row)

cursor.close()
con.close()
```

El objeto `cursor` es iterable, por tanto se puede recorrer con un `for variable in iterable`. En cada iteración una fila de la tabla resultante de la consulta se asigna a la variable `row`. La variable la lamamos `row` o podemos llamarla `fila` o como queramos.